# Slow query and use of indexes in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT final_query.chr
     , final_query.start
     , final_query.end
     , co.chr
     , co.start
     , co.end
     , final_query.count
FROM (SELECT ed.chr
     , ed.start
     , ed.end
     , case when e.bin1=ed.bin then e.bin2 else e.bin1 end AS target
     , count
     FROM (SELECT * FROM coordinates
     WHERE chr="chr1" AND (start between 3960000 AND 4000000 OR end between 3960000 AND 4000000)
     ) ed
     JOIN counts e ON (e.bin1 = ed.bin OR e.bin2=ed.bin)
     SORT BY count LIMIT 1,20)
AS final_query
JOIN coordinates co ON final_query.target=co.bin;
```

and the output of `EXPLAINED` is:

```
+------+-------------+-------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+----------+------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table       | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows     | Extra                              |
+------+-------------+-------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+----------+------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | e           | ALL    | bin1,bin2     | NULL    | NULL    | NULL  | 30763816 | Using filesort                     |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | coordinates | ref    | PRIMARY,chr   | chr     | 22      | const |     4929 | Using index condition; Using where |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | co          | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 22      | func  |        1 | Using where                        |
+------+-------------+-------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+----------+------------------------------------+
```

What I am doing is to perform the following query of table `coordinates`, which has field `chr` indexed. So, in the subquery shown below, I filter those rows that match my conditions.

```
... (SELECT * FROM coordinates
     WHERE chr="chr1" AND (start between 3960000 AND 4000000 OR end between 3960000 AND 4000000)
) ...
```

This table outputs field `bin`, also indexed. This field `bin` links with `bin1` and `bin2` both from table counts and indexed as well. So, here, what I want is to get all those rows in table `counts` having `coordinates.bin` in fields `bin1` and `bin2`. Why in this step no index is used?

Besides of it, I would like to add an `ORDER BY` in my query, just before the `LIMIT` statement. But it slows too much my query. I don't know why, because it have to sort a maximum of 4000 rows...

How can I optimize my query?

My tables, from the `DESCRIBE` statement:

**Table counts**

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| bin1  | varchar(20) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| bin2  | varchar(20) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| count | float(6,2)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**Table coordinates**

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| bin   | varchar(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| chr   | varchar(20) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| start | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| end   | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: The logic seems fine except for the coordinate selection.  Shouldn't `(start between 3960000 AND 4000000 OR end between 3960000 AND 4000000)` be `(start between 3960000 AND 4000000  -->AND<--   end between 3960000 AND 4000000)`?

Comment: No. For example, suppose that I have a bin with a range from 1 to 1000 and another bin with a range from 1001 and 2000. I want both bins when I query for a range from 500 to 1500. This is only possible using `OR`.